# How to interpret units of measurement like $\text{kg m/s}^2$?

Tags: forces, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Let's first take an example. I understand that if a car has $v=20 \,\text{m/s}$ this means that every second it moves $20 \,\text{m}$. But how should I interpret units that are multiplied like $\text{N m}$? Or even $\text{kg m/s}^2$ which is a multiplication divided by seconds squared? This makes no physical sense to me.

Comment: N m: When you apply one newton of force on an object at one meter from its axis of rotation, you’re applying one newton-meter of torque.

Comment: km m/s$^2$: The force that makes a one kilogram object accelerate at one meter per second per second.

Comment: But don’t try to “interpret” every unit you come across. For example, one statcoulomb is one g$^{1/2}$cm$^{3/2}$s$^{-1}$. Units are whatever they need to be to make an equation consistent. The *equation* is what should make physical sense to you.

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question about a topic that is often confusing for beginners in physics.

Answer (score 5):

- The unit $1 \, \mathrm{kg}$ can be interpretted in the way that you have 1 kilogram of mass.

Division with units is typically fairly easy to interpret:

- The unit $1 \, \mathrm{kg/s}$ can be interpretted in the way that you have 1 more kilogram for each second that passes. This is the change in the mass over time.
- The unit $1 \, \mathrm{kg/s^2}$ can be interpretted in the way that your amount of kilograms increases with 1 more kilogram per second for each passing second. The speed with which you are changing the mass is increasing.

Multiplied units can be harder to interpret, but let's try:

- The unit $1 \, \mathrm{kg\cdot m}$ can be interpretted in the way that you have 1 kilogram of mass *and* you have 1 metre of distance. In physics, this could be a torque (perpendicular force times distance from hinge point, $\tau=F\cdot r$, will cause an angular turn) or this could be an amount of work that is being done, so transferred energy (parallel force times distance over which something is moved, $W=F\cdot d$, means that work is done on - energy is added to - the moved object).
- The unit $4 \, \mathrm{kg\cdot m}$ can be interpretted in the way that you have 2 kilograms of mass and you have 2 metres of distance. Or you might have 1 kilogram of mass and 4 metres of distance, since that might be equivalent when considering the resulting effect, which would be the case for torque and for work.

And what if we have both unit multiplication *and* unit division in the same unit bundle?

- The unit $1 \, \mathrm{kg\cdot m/s}$ can be interpretted in the way that you have 1 more kilogram *or* 1 more metre for each second that passes. Having one more of either is maybe equivalent when considering the resulting effect. This can be the change in the torque or energy over time.
- The unit $2 \, \mathrm{kg\cdot m/s}$ can be interpretted in the way that you have 1 more kilogram *and* 1 more metre for each second that passes. Or maybe 2 more kilograms and 0 more metres for each passing second, which would be equivalent when considering the resulting effect.

And so on.

Comment: Very nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

At first I will start from a Newton definition, $\large {1 N = 1 kg~\frac {1m}{1s} / 1s}$, so one Newton is a force needed to give one kilogram speed increase by 1m/s each second. 2N force- same speed increase conditions for 2kg object and so on.

Compound multiplied units like $N\times m$ are best understood if you would use non-unit values in them, like
$2N \cdot 3m = 3N \cdot 2m = 6Nm$ (commutative property of multiplication). This read like, torque given by 2N force at point 3 meters from pivot is SAME as torque given by 3N force, at point 2 meters from pivot OR 6 newtons at 1 meter from pivot. And so I hope that $6~\text{Nm}$ now makes sense to you.

So this informs us that same Physical quantity can be achieved in multiple ways.

Lets take another famous example,- we all pay bills for electricity, but rarely think what Watt-hours means. Say your used electricity indicator shows, $100Wh$, this means that you *could use* 100W equivalent light bulb for 1 hour OR you could have used tiny device using 1W power for 100 hours. Both electricity usage schemes will spent SAME $360kJ$ energy as per formula $E=Pt$. So to say we pay money for spent electricity **energy**.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert physical quantities like length into numbers that we can work with algebraically, we need to introduce arbitrary *reference scales* in terms of which we measure everything else. For example, we need to define a given length as "one meter" -- once we do that, we can think of every other length as fractions of one meter.

In the SI system, there are 7 "base units", or reference scales. For mechanics, only three are relevant -- the meter, second, and kilogram, which physically measure length, time, and mass. Once we define these reference scales, all physical quantities can be assigned a numerical value. Derived units, like a Newton, are simply convenient shorthand for expression combinations of those three scales (e.g., ${\rm 1\ N}=1\ {\rm kg\cdot m \cdot s^{-2}}$).

However, even though we have defined a numerical value for all physical quantities, the actual numerical value is *arbitrary*, because it *depends on our arbitrary choice of reference scales*. In particular, if we decide to *change* the reference scales, then the numerical values of various measurable quantities, like say, the speed of light, will also change. By keeping track of units, we keep track of *exactly how a given quantity will change* if we change the reference scales.

This is useful because (possibly among other reasons)

1. sometimes we do change reference scales (for example, we might find it more convenient to use centimeters instead of meters),
2. any equation in physics must be true independent of the arbitrary reference scales we introduced, so we can use dimensional analysis to check that any equation we write down is even theoretically possible,
3. it allows us to identify certain, special quantities (dimensionless quantities) which *don't* depend on our choice of reference scale, and are therefore somehow intrinsic to the physical problem -- a classic example would be the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number), which measures the tendency of a fluid flow to be turbulent.

In simple cases, it is possible to give a more "intuitive" picture of a certain unit, like ${\rm m\cdot s^{-1}}$ for velocity could be interpreted as the number of meters traveled in one second. However, as one deals with more complicated quantities, it becomes less and less useful to come up with an "intuitive" picture. In fact, there are even situations where the same set of units mean different things in different contexts -- for example, $1\ {\rm N\cdot m}$ could be a measure of torque about an axis, or the work done to lift an object in a gravitational field. Then one has to fall back on the rigorous meaning, which is to do with how quantities scale under a change of reference scales.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I tell noobs:

$$ g = 22\,{\rm mph/s} $$

forces them to think delta v over delta t.

If you throw mass in, then it's delta p over delta t.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to consider that units are arbitrary scales we assign to physical quantities. The laws of physics remain the same no matter if we measure in meters, feet or furlongs.

The combined units are useful for calculation, but they do not have a deeper physical significance than any of the other units. We could measure speed in knots and distance in knot-seconds, or even measure speeds in knots and distance still in meters. It would just be annoying to reason about, but the calculations would work fine. [This list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physical_quantities) has most common quantities represented not as specific units, but as combinations of time, distance and mass (and a few others).

Dimensional analysis in metric / SI units works particularly well because the units were chosen to be consistent for the most common physics equations.

For basic combinations like the unit of torque, $\mathrm{N \times m}$, you can reason that larger force (N) and larger distance from center (m) both increase the result. Compare with the unit for spring constant, $\mathrm{N / m}$, where a larger displacement (m) means the spring is less stiff.

There are a few basic principles we can deduce:

- Quantities in dividend increase the result
- Quantities in divider reduce the result
- Squared or cubed units of distance (m², m³) often relate to surface area or volume.
- Units of time (s, s², s³) often relate to integrals and derivatives over time, like acceleration.
- Square roots of units (e.g. in $\mathrm{V/\sqrt{Hz}}$) arise from cases where another quantity (in this case power, W) is related to the square of it.

More complex units cannot be interpreted without knowing the underlying physical equations they are based on. A comment by Ghoster mentioned the SI equivalent unit for [statcoloumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb) which looks quite perplexing:

$$\mathrm{statC} = \mathrm{cm^{3/2} \times g^{1/2} \times s^{-1}}$$

We can try to rearrange it to make more sense:

$$\mathrm{statC} = \mathrm{\frac{\sqrt{g \times cm^3}}{s}}$$

or

$$\mathrm{statC}^2 = \mathrm{\frac{g \times cm^3}{s^2}}$$

Applying the rules above, this would lead us to believe it is the second derivative over time of some quantity that increases by mass and volume.

Digging further gives us the definitions *"The statcoulomb is such that if two stationary objects each carry a charge of 1 statC and are 1 cm apart, they will electrically repel each other with a force of 1 dyne."* and *"The dyne is defined as the force required to accelerate a mass of one gram at a rate of one centimetre per second squared."*

This leads us to different form:

$$\mathrm{statC}^2 = \mathrm{\frac{g \times cm}{s^2} \times cm^2}$$

Here the first term is a convoluted way to express force: greater mass and distance of movement in shorter time is a larger force. The second term is a different distance: the separation between charges. Because the force depends on the product of two charges, we end up with the square or square root for a single charge.

**There was no relation to volume.** Looking at the units only can be misleading, because one `cm` can represent a different distance than another, but they all get combined in the unit.

Comment: ah the statC...does it tell is charge is made up?

Answer (score 0):

Most Physical Units can be Written in terms of product of different powers of 7 fundamental quantities which are length(L),mass(M),time(T),Electric current(I),Temperature(K),Amount of substance(N),Luminous intensity(J), These are called dimensions of the unit.

So in short, Most physical quantities can be written as $[M^aL^bT^cI^dK^eN^fJ^g]$. Notice that The representation is simply product of The powers of fundamental quantities involved in the equation that you are trying to interpret, Which means any two derived quantites (Units) may have same Dimensions even If the Quantity represent two different physical entities and two different physical scenarios.

This brings us to the interesting part, Here is the example for two different physical quantities having Same Dimensions(Hence same standard units)

1)Torque: $(N \cdot m)$, Torque is the moment of force, When 1 $N$ of force is applied at end to A hinged rod of length 1$m$, A torque of $1$ $(N \cdot m)$ is produced, This is one way of interpreting it

2)Work/Energy: $(N \cdot m)$, When An object is displaced By $1m$ under the action of $1$ $N$ force, $1$ $(N \cdot m)$ or 1 $J$ of work is Done

As You can See The interpretation Is easy to do for equations as long as you can get physical sense/use of equations and scenarios involved with that, To interpret Units just take each $1$ of the unit and try to make sense of it using the equation in that particular physical situation, Because as I said, Different Physical scenarios might Have different physical quantities with same units.

Note:Generally, In an interpretation,Division show inverse dependance with the final quantity, Meaning Divisions can be interpreted as rates